# GraalVM / Nashorn compatibility for Java enum

Tags: java, compatibility, nashorn, graalvm

I'm playing with GraalVM (v21.2.0), trying to assess backward compatibility with Nashorn.
Many things work pretty well including Java Map, Collection, Beans handling.
But I have the following problem with enum:

```
public static enum Color { GREEN, BLUE }

@Test
public void testNashornEnum() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager lManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine lEngine = lManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    Bindings lBindings = new SimpleBindings();
    lBindings.put("color", Color.GREEN);
    Object lResult = lEngine.eval("color == 'GREEN'", lBindings);
    System.out.println("Nashorn: " + lResult);
}

@Test
public void testGraalEnum() throws ScriptException {
    System.setProperty("polyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false");
    ScriptEngine lEngine = GraalJSScriptEngine.create(
        null,
        Context.newBuilder("js").allowHostClassLookup((s) -> true)
                                .allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL)
                                .allowExperimentalOptions(true)
                                .option("js.nashorn-compat", "true")
    );
    
    Bindings lBindings = new SimpleBindings();
    lBindings.put("color", Color.GREEN);
    Object lResult = lEngine.eval("color == 'GREEN'", lBindings);
    System.out.println("GraalVM: " + lResult);      
}
```

Test case testNashornEnum outputs "true", whereas testGraalEnum() outputs "false".

Does anyone know a way to fix this gap?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get anything sorted with enums? I have exactly the same issue. Everything working so nicely otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately no :-(

Comment: The only option I can see is, in GraalVM case, converting input bindings into Map of Maps and Collections recursively (this also includes converting beans to Maps), and within this process replacing enum values by their string representation.

Comment: Tx. I ended up using JsProxy to convert enums fields to/from strings.

Comment: Sorry mean to say ProxyObject